# Number sequence interchanging between two companies in dynamics AX 4.0

Tags: axapta, x++

When i open two workspaces in dynamics ax 4.0, one having DMO company and other having DAT company. When am accesing both the companies the number sequence series is getting interchanged between these two companies. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the AX user interface or are you writing code using `changecompany`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [virtual companies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834382%28AX.10%29.aspx).